# Help with Access Point configuration, please

Tags: wifi, pi-4, debian, access-point

I'm running Debian v.12 on a Pi4B, and I'm having trouble getting my wifi Access Point to work. Specifically, I want the Pi to act as a local server without being connected to the house network. The network appears to be running on the Pi but it does not show as an available network to other devices (laptop, phone). I'm pasting all the relevant files and outputs below (separated by stars for readability), and if anyone can help me figure out my configuration error I'd be grateful:
(*edit: some of the data below reflects that I am currently connected to the house wifi in order to post this: house wifi is ESSID:"WIFIE3B371")

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WIFIE3B371"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 28:56:5A:E3:B3:74   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

---

```
$ service hostapd status
* hostapd.service - Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-03 08:05:06 EST; 18min ago
       Docs: man:hostapd(8)
    Process: 831 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, st>
   Main PID: 926 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3912)
        CPU: 95ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             `-926 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Jan 03 08:05:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting hostapd.service - Access point and authentication server for Wi>
Jan 03 08:05:06 raspberrypi hostapd[831]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Jan 03 08:05:06 raspberrypi hostapd[831]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Jan 03 08:05:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started hostapd.service - Access point and authentication server for Wi->
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

---

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:7c:f1:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 128  bytes 11769 (11.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 128  bytes 11769 (11.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2603:6010:7e42:8a00:cabf:7819:6f76:b4b5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::66d9:c124:5fb9:44f6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2603:6010:7e42:8a00::6  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:7c:f1:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11403  bytes 8894360 (8.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7266  bytes 1243992 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/default/hostapd
#<OP: lots of comment lines, just one actual line I added during setup>
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=TypeToKF
hw_mode=g
channel=6
wmm_enabled=0
#macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=sallywag
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

---

```
 $ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
#<Note from OP: all lines in this file are commented out>
```

Comment: always format printouts same as code here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the information posted is not formatted for read-ability (use a code-fence for that stuff, please), and as the OS is Debian, it's unclear if network config is the same as in RPi OS.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped trying to figure out what you had done when I got to hostapd (you haven't explained WHAT YOU DID).

Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm uses NetworkManager which can be configured as a hotspot from the advanced option of the networking tool and has a sub menu to configure Access Point.

Ignore any of the existing tutorials which are out of date.

See [Host a wireless network on your Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#host-a-wireless-network-on-your-raspberry-pi) (although I have not tried this).